# How to do Late Binding in Java

Tags: java, android, soap, xml-serialization, android-ksoap2

I have some Dot Net code for generating request in Soap Web-Service Accessing.

```
    List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>{
new Employee{firstname="Aamir",lastname="Hasan",age=20},
new Employee{firstname="awais",lastname="Hasan",age=50},
new Employee{firstname="Bill",lastname="Hasan",age=70},
new Employee{firstname="sobia",lastname="khan",age=80},  
};
```

Now I want to same thing in Android.
So how can i create such kind of Late binding in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList(new Employee[]{new Employee("Aamir", "Hasan", 20), new Employee("awais", "Hasan", 50)});
```

Note, you have to create a proper constructor with all parameters in Java. The "{parameter=value}" notation doesn't work.

Update:

By proper constructor, I mean an explicit constructor for all your properties:

```
public class Employee {

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        // set property values
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please explain (...) I want run time properties for my object.